# SwiftUI List Animation for Expand and Collapse

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I cannot get my SwiftUI list to animate the expanding and collapsing of rows. (Xcode 12.0 Beta & Simulator)

I have Sections and each section has a number of elements. When I click on the section I want it to toggle expand/collapse.

I don't know where I should specify this animation modifier.

```
import SwiftUI

struct MySection : Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name:String
}

let mySections = [MySection(name: "s1"),MySection(name: "s2"),MySection(name: "s3")]

struct Content: View {
    @State var isExpanded : [Bool] = [false,false,false]
    @State var rotation = 0.0

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(mySections.indices) { index in
                Section(header: Text("\(mySections[index].name)")) {
                    if isExpanded[index] {
                        ForEach(0...4, id: \.self) {
                           Text("Number: \($0)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        EmptyView()
                    }
                }.onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        isExpanded[index].toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not understand the comment

Comment: I tested your code on Xcode 12 - it works, ie. sections are expanded/collapsed with animation. That's it.

Comment: The animation is not working for me on the simulator, I do not have a device available right now

Comment: The following might be helpful - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61698182/swiftui-animation-transition-within-scrollview-behaving-strange